# Dispatcher only draws last object from array

Tags: c#, wpf, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional array of `Tile` objects.

My program starts by selecting a `Tile` in a random position (eg. (0,0)),  visits a random neighbour `Tile`, marks it as visited and moves to the next neighbour until there are no unvisited neighbours available.

This is my code:

```
while (HasUnvisitedNeighbours())
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            CurrentTile.Draw();
        }));
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    });

    //1. Choose randomly a neighbour
    List<char> Keys = new List<char>(CurrentTile.Neighbours.Keys);
    char randomKey = Keys[rnd.Next(Keys.Count)];

    CurrentTile = CurrentTile.Neighbours[randomKey];
    CurrentTile.HasBeenVisited = true;
}
```

I've debugged through my program, and I've confirmed that:

```
CurrentTile = CurrentTile.Neighbours[randomKey];
```

Correctly changes each loop to a correct neighbour and that the loop will stop when there are no unvisited neighbours next to it.

But in:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        CurrentTile.Draw();
    }));
    Thread.Sleep(500);
});
```

`CurrentTile.Draw()` always seems to have the same value, in the debugger (the last value of `CurrentTile = CurrentTile.Neighbours[randomKey];`. So it seems the dispatcher waits for the whole loop to finish and THEN it draws the last `Tile` object.

My intention is to draw the current `Tile` -> move to a neighbour -> mark it as current tile -> draw the current tile ->...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `BeginInvoke` is scheduling (queuing) some "work" to be done by a particular `Dispatcher` i.e. typically your main UI message loop/handling thread.

When you are in your "while loop" you are already processing/doing work on the `Dispatcher` thread (but it is for a different/previous message).

(Normally) The `Dispatcher` can't process the next "dispatch" message from the queue, till you have finished what you are doing and control returns to the `Dispatcher`...and then the `Dispatcher` can choose which message to process next (which might be yours, or it might be someone elses depending on priority).

(for a more indepth description of how the windows message loop/dispatcher works, see this: [Does using dispatcher.Invoke make my thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526678/does-using-dispatcher-invoke-make-my-thread-safe))

This bit of code will start off a `Task` which will keep causing random tiles to be visited until all your `HasUnvisitedNeighbours()` returns false.

You could alternatively use `.Invoke` (the synchronous version) instead of the `.BeginInvoke` and `.Wait` combination.

Note: it's often said to be preferable to use `.BeginInvoke`, rather than `.Invoke` as in certain situations `.Invoke` can deadlock....but I think in this case you could use either.

You could do your `HasUnvisitedNeighbours();` and then the the `.Draw`, and selection of next tile in just a single "invoke" if you preferred.

However, I split it into 2 "invokes" as you could restructure it possibly so that you got the list of unvisited tiles only once (by querying all the tiles .HasBeenVisited property), and then only modify that list instead of asking all the tiles again - that's because you are the one visiting the tiles...so you know if they have now been visited.

```
void VisitAllNeighbours()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            bool bHasUnvisitedNeighbours = false;

            DispatcherOperation dispopunvisitedtiles = Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                bHasUnvisitedNeighbours = HasUnvisitedNeighbours();
            };

            dispopunvisitedtiles.Wait();

            if (!bHasUnvisitedNeighbours)
                break;

            DispatcherOperation dispopvisitnext = Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                CurrentTile.Draw();

                //1. Choose randomly a neighbour
                List<char> Keys = new List<char>(CurrentTile.Neighbours.Keys);
                randomKey = Keys[rnd.Next(Keys.Count)];

                CurrentTile = CurrentTile.Neighbours[randomKey];
                CurrentTile.HasBeenVisited = true;

            }));

            // Take out this "wait" if you want multiple "visits" to be
            // pending/scheduled instead of only one at a time - be
            // careful that your "random visiting" selection code
            // doesn't cause too many "visits" to be outstanding though!
            //
            // Note: each visit never occurs at the same time as another
            // one as the "Dispatcher"/message loop is providing the
            // serialization.

            dispopvisitnext.Wait();

            Thread.Sleep(500); // if you want a "delay" between each Tile visit
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh I see, but why does it only queue the last `Tile` instead of say the first. Also, is this the wrong implementation if I want to draw what path I take? I also tried a dispatcherTimer but it made the drawing  in the first tick.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526678/does-using-dispatcher-invoke-make-my-thread-safe   .... is a good description of the way Windows' messageloop dispatcher works

Comment: it's only the last tile that gets drawn, because CurrentTile is set to the last tile when it comes out the loop...it's only when it comes out the the loop....that the CurrentTile.Draw() will get called......and CurrentTile at that point...now contains your last tile.....not your 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc....Remember, your "beginvoke" is only queued....and only gets processed the next time the "dispatcher" is allowed/gets around to processing it.

Answer (score 0):

> So it seems the dispatcher waits for the whole loop to finish and THEN it draws the last Tile object.

Yes, `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` schedules a delegate to be eventually executed on the dispatcher thread. But why are you starting a new task only to call `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`? This doesn't make much sense.

You could use the synchronous `Invoke` method to wait until the method has been excecuted on the dispatcher thread:

```
while (HasUnvisitedNeighbours())
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => CurrentTile.Draw()));
    Thread.Sleep(500);

    List<char> Keys = new List<char>(CurrentTile.Neighbours.Keys);
    char randomKey = Keys[rnd.Next(Keys.Count)];

    CurrentTile = CurrentTile.Neighbours[randomKey];
    CurrentTile.HasBeenVisited = true;
}
```

**Edit:**

The UI thread cannot both execute your loop and update the UI simultaneously. You could try to run your code on a background thread:

```
private void Method()
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (HasUnvisitedNeighbours())
        {
            await Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => CurrentTile.Draw()));
            await Task.Delay(500);

            List<char> Keys = new List<char>(CurrentTile.Neighbours.Keys);
            char randomKey = Keys[rnd.Next(Keys.Count)];

            CurrentTile = CurrentTile.Neighbours[randomKey];
            CurrentTile.HasBeenVisited = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: nice, I see the full path instead of the last `Tile`!, my only problem now is that the invoke() call seems to block the ui thread until the full drawing is completed, is there a way to see how each `Tile` is drawn, one at a time?

Comment: Doesn't CurrentTile.Draw() draw only a single tile? Of course the UI thread will be blocked during this time.

Comment: Yep CurrentTile.Draw() draws only one tile(4 lines), but the UI thread gets blocked until the full loop is completed, then it draws all the tiles all at once,which I don't understand as Invoke() should freeze the UI thread until 1 Tile is drawn not all of them.

Comment: Not as far as I now, when I press a button in my program, it initializes the array, and then calls this function (which only does what is shown)

Comment: @ColinSmith: Yes, as mentioned, the CurrentTile.Draw() method will always block the UI thread. This is expected.